Deeplink to app subscription page (Microsoft Teams)
I know for a fact that we can build a deeplink to an app install page from this documentation, however I want to redirect the user to a more specific page, especially the subscription page and the page after user click on "Add to a team" button.
Is it doable?

Currently this is not possible, only the documented deeplinks are supported.

thank you for the confirmation, also how and where can I request this as a feature?

Sure, you can post this request here https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472.
